# PHP supress 3rd party library warning

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using NET_EPP library from CentralNIC (https://github.com/centralnic/php-epp/)
At some point my script calls

```
@$frame = new \Net_EPP_Frame_Command_Login(); //the EPP framework throws a warning otherwise
```

Note @ in the beginning of the line, this is done for purpose to suppress a warning thrown here by a 3rd party library.

So, the constructor of Net_EPP_Frame_Command_Login calls its parent constructor

```
class Net_EPP_Frame_Command_Login extends Net_EPP_Frame_Command {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('login');
```

That looks like

```
class Net_EPP_Frame_Command extends Net_EPP_Frame {

        function __construct($command, $type) {
            $this->type = $type;
```

This part in turn throws me 2 warnings -

```
WARNING: Missing argument 2 for Net_EPP_Frame_Command::__construct()
NOTICE: Undefined variable: type
```

How can I suppress those warnings without modifying the library?

**Update**

Interestingly, if I talk to my server directly it does not display the warning although if I get the page contents using curl it does.

```
$args = array("domainName" => $_POST['domain'], "tld" => $_POST['tld']);
$action = "CheckAvailabilityActionByModule";
$msg = new CommsMessage($action,$args);
$reply = TestServer::main($msg->encode());
$reply = CommsMessage::decodeReply($reply);
```

Works fine as I am talking directly to the server. But

```
$reply = $client->getAvailabilityByModule($_POST['domain'], $_POST['tld']);
```

Does not because this request is done through curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change error_reporting (all but no warning or notice):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
```

Or setup your own [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). `error_reporting` settings will have no effect in this case:

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    // do what you want in case of error

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For details please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
Turn off all error reporting.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to suppress all error reporting because it is a production environment this will make debugging impossible. Furthermore, this is supposed to generate an API response therefore no unintended output should be present

Answer (score 0):

Either give both arguments a value or remove one value from your __construct function.

Comment: It is a third party library that I do not want to modify